Unitary equivalence of two positive operators
Let $P\in\mathcal{B(\mathcal{H})}$ be a positive contraction. Suppose it is given that $P\cdot \max\{\frac{1}{2},P\}^{-1}$ is unitarily equivalent to $P$. Then is it necessarily true that $P$ is a projection?

No. Written in terms of infinite matrices, here is a counterexample:
$$P = \begin{pmatrix}
\ddots\\
& 1\\
& & 1\\
& & & \frac{1}{2}\\
& & & & \frac{1}{4}\\
& & & & & \frac{1}{8}\\
& & & & & & \ddots
\end{pmatrix}$$
$$P \cdot \max\{\frac{1}{2}, P\}^{-1} = \begin{pmatrix}
\ddots\\
& 1\\
& & 1\\
& & & 1\\
& & & & \frac{1}{2}\\
& & & & & \frac{1}{4}\\
& & & & & & \ddots
\end{pmatrix}$$
Then $P$ and $P \cdot \max\{\frac{1}{2}, P\}^{-1}$ are clearly unitarily equivalent, but $P$ is not a projection.
